# docker stack deploy with mongo volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

i'm starting my docker stack with command:

```
docker stack deploy --with-registry-auth -c docker-compose.yml app
```

my docker-compose.yml contains entry for mongo:

```
mongodb:
    image: mongo:3.6
    volumes:
      - mongodb:/var/lib/mongodb
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    networks:
      - backend
    environment:
      - AUTH=yes
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "100m"
        max-file: "5"
    deploy:
        replicas: 1
        placement:
          constraints: [node.hostname == hostname]

networks:
  frontend:
  backend:

volumes:
  mongodb:
```

im stoping docker stack with `docker stack rm app` Why i'm losing data in mongo after second start with same command `docker stack deploy --with-registry-auth -c docker-compose.yml app` ? How to avoid id?

Thanks, smola

Answer (score 1):

ok, i've found answer..

based on image:mongo:3.6 [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/2e3e1bdbb31389c8bc8d43f5a3cc439134b7956b/3.6/Dockerfile), there are already specified two 
volumes: `VOLUME /data/db /data/configdb`

so in docker-compose.yml need to mount host directories into that volumes:

```
mongodb:
    image: mongo:3.6
    volumes:
      - /sampledir/db:/data/db                <-----
      - /sampledir/configdb:/data/configdb    <-----
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:27017:27017
    networks:
      - backend
    environment:
      - AUTH=yes
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "100m"
        max-file: "5"
    deploy:
        replicas: 1
        placement:
          constraints: [node.hostname == hostname]
```

Comment: Mounting /data/db should be enough for persisting data, /data/configdb is not necessary.